# how to check if a class having a css property and change other class' css property based on that class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

like in this example,
when `toggle-sidebar` has class `active`
the `sidebar` its width should change to `width:0;` and  `content` class' `margin-left` should change from `60px` to `0`

here is the code for reference:

```css
.sidebar{
    width: 60px;
}
  
.content{
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="toggle-sidebar">icon</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main d-flex">
        <div class="sidebar ">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Dashboard</li>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
                <li>About us</li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content flex-fill"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a class on the `wrapper` div and style according to that, then you'll only need to toggle said class.

Comment: any solution by using javascipt

Comment: @JunaidShaikh the question title says without jQuery, then you comment "*any* solution using javascript" - well, that includes jQuery. You will have to be a lot more specific about what kind of solutions are acceptable and what are not. I strongly suggest updating the question to reflect this, and maybe include any javascript code you already have running on the page, so that people can tailor their responses to your situation. Thank you.

Comment: @JunaidShaikh your question has been answered, then you edited it but left the same situation that the answer does solve, but apparently what you want is a CSS-only solution that would work in many different markup situations. That is not how CSS works, it is tightly coupled with HTML and so when your HTML changes, the CSS in this case will have to change as well. Kindly either update the question to your specific use-case so you can get an answer to your actual need, or mark the given answer as correct, since it solves the currently given scenario. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can use CSS selector specificity (good reads [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)) in order to override some styles based on some conditions such as markup structure, screen size, etc.

In particular to your example, you can exploit the fact that the `content` element is right after the `sidebar` element in the DOM, and make use of the `+` CSS operator which targets an element matching the 2nd part of the selector (after the `+`) only if it appears immediately after an element matching the 1st part. Like so:

```
.sidebar + .content {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Adding this rule inside your `<style>` tag will apply `margin-left: 0;` to `.content` only if `.sidebar` is rendered right before it, and being a more specific selector, it will override the initial `.content` declaration. You will see in the Elements panel of your Developer Tools that the `margin-left: 60px;` rule is crossed out.

Also, to apply the margin only when the sidebar is open, you could use the same technique like this:

```
.sidebar.sidebar-open + .content {
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: but what if i want to change the css properties of classes which are not siblings

Comment: @JunaidShaikh then just find the correct CSS selector for that specific case. There's no "one size fits all" solution here, the markup will influence the CSS selectors you will write. Without the specific markup you're dealing with, nobody can give you a solution in these constraints.

Comment: @JunaidShaikh for the question as it stands now, this answer solves the issue. Please either mark this answer as accepted or update your question if there's more to it. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the question, and looking for a solution or technique which can help in multiple situations.

Comment: @JunaidShaikh without knowing what you actually need, what you're asking for is a compendium of all possible problems and their solutions (traditionally would be flagged as "Too Broad"). I'm sorry, StackOverflow doesn't quite work like that, please either do your own research, or ask about a set of situations so that people can provide a corresponding set of solutions. Thank you.